# About Web Page Development with Drop down menu & submit button

Tags: drop-down-menu

I want to develop a web page with following details.

I have three different drop down menu & 9 images & 1 submit button.

So according to drop down combination I can see 9 different images with help of Submit button.

Please suggest me .

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use bootstrap for your html responsive designs like drop down menu and submit buttons and javascript related functionality.
Find bootstrap tutorial in tutorialspoint.com.

All you need if just to use the appropriate class in the tag to make a drop down.
Like example:

```
 <div class="nav-bar">
 <ul class="dropdown">
  <li>my list</>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

thats how easy it can be to make a drop down menu with bootstrap.
Find the tutorial or search for it in google with this search query: "tutorialspoint: bootstrap tutorial"

Comment: Actually I know about  button , Image display & drop down menu.
 
But I am unable to make page with adding all three option as well as could not make action plan for different drop down option.